# Calculate repeated measures difference in R

Tags: r, difference

df:

```
ID     cat1
A0001   358
A0001   279
A0049   324
A0049   358
A0049   432
```

To calculate the difference in value in cat1 between the repeated measures (by ID). The expected output df should look like:

```
 ID    cat1 cat1_diff
A0001   358   NA
A0001   279   -79
A0049   324   NA
A0049   358   26
A0049   432   74
```

I would appreciate any insights how to do this in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`, and the `lag` function:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
       mutate(cat1_diff = cat1 - lag(cat1))

Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: ID

     ID cat1 cat1_diff
1 A0001  358        NA
2 A0001  279       -79
3 A0049  324        NA
4 A0049  358        34
5 A0049  432        74
```

Comment: this one works! Thanks so much jeremycg